# how to solve 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects' error

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have a dataframe which kind of looks like this:

```
           date        holiday  item_cnt_day    shop_id      cnt_sem    cnt_mes     cnt_year
0        2013-01-01       1         0.0           59         0.000000   0.000000    0.000000
1        2013-01-02       1         0.0           59         0.000000   0.000000    0.000000
2        2013-01-03       1         0.0           59         0.000000   0.000000    0.000000
3        2013-01-04       1         0.0           59         0.000000   0.000000    0.000000
4        2013-01-05       0         0.0           59         0.000000   0.000000    0.000000
          ......         ...        ...           ...           ...        ...         ...
1029    2015-10-27        0         4.0           36         1.142857   0.321429    0.024658
1030    2015-10-28        0         1.0           36         1.285714   0.357143    0.027397
1031    2015-10-29        0         1.0           36         1.142857   0.392857    0.030137
1032    2015-10-30        0         4.0           36         1.714286   0.535714    0.041096
1033    2015-10-31        0         1.0           36         1.857143   0.571429    0.043836
```

dates start from 2013-01-01 to 2015-10-31 and this range of dates is for every shop_id, this is, for every shop_id I have that range for the dates, therefore, I have duplicate dates, but what I'm trying to do is to only have those dates which comes after the first 365 days per shop_id and I'm trying to do that by using this function:

```
def no_todos(df, shops):
    # shops is a list of shops and there are 60 shops in this list
    # df is the dataframe to be operated in the loop

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(df)

    # Here I'm trying to only keep those observations which come after the first 365 days for each shop
    for t in shops:
        new_df['shop_id'][t] = df[365::]
    return new_df
```

However, I'm having this error: *Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects.* Does anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the question properly, you are looking to keep only the days after the first 365 of each shop and store these in your new dataframe, right?

Comment: Yes, and the answer you provided does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the dataframe, then do a groupby and then do negative tail. Negative tail is not implemented in groupby `tail` method so you need to create your own function. This will skip the first rows of each group

```
df.sort_values(['shop_id', 'date'], ascending=[True, True])

def negative_tail(group, n):
    return group._selected_obj[group.cumcount(ascending=True) >= n]

final_result = negative_tail(df.groupby('shop_id'), 365).copy()
```